# Chai Should Object Equality

Tags: node.js, chai

I am trying to verify that the response body here is returning {} but not sure the proper chai syntax because I know when I do a console.log(response.body) it's showing {}

```
response.body.should.shallowDeepEqual({});
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the correct usage of shallowDeepEqual. Are you getting errors? You can just stringify both objects and see if their string representations are equal.

```
response.body.toString().should.equal({}.toString());
```